# Jenkins Pipeline and SSH keys - Git agent works, SSH Agent doesn't

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm trying to use Git repos in my pipeline, but I'm running into authentication issues.  Ultimately I need to use 'tsrc' but authentication is failing even on simple examples.

Here's the simplest example I can come up with.  This works.

```
  stage('Hello') {
    steps {
      git branch: 'master', credentialsId: 'Github-SSH', url: 'git@****'
      echo 'Hello World'
    }
  }
```

This doesn't.

```
steps {
  withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'Github-SSH', keyFileVariable: 'KEY_FILE')])             
    {
    sh '''
            eval `ssh-agent -s`
            ssh-add ${KEY_FILE}
            git clone git@****
    '''
    }
  }
}
```

The second example gives the error:

```
Host key verification failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

try replacing ``` with """ such that `${KEY_FILE}` is interpreted as a variable.
P.S. I met behavior when declarative pipelines act differently from Groovy. So, not sure.